# Fix text in message box on contact page for "How to add or remove login credentials" item

Tags: bug, contact

https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

> [image]

1. Link just opens a profile page. open at least settings page.
2. "my logins" is in the bot left, not top right.

Comment: You may not want to use a picture that clearly shows your email...

Comment: @Laurel it's not my email ┐(︶▽︶)┌

Comment: The "my logins" link used to be at the top right of your profile page. That popup just hasn't been updated in a *very* long time. ;) That may be contributing to why we get so many requests asking how to do this simple task.